# Residual sum of squares and Lasso regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Residual sum of squares (RSS) is defined by formula:
$$RSS(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{p} \beta_{j}x_{ij})^2$$. In Lasso we minimize the RSS subject to $\sum_{j=1}^{p} |\beta_{j}| \leq s$.

Suppose that $p=2$, I don't see why $RSS$ is constant on elipses that are centered around $\hat\beta$ which is least square estimator. I don't even see why function $RSS(\beta)$ is ellipse for $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$. I have tried the sum write in simple form but it didn't helped me.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lasso the constraint $\sum_{j=1}^p |\beta_j|\leq s$ is not an elipse. You are considering the betas for which $\|\beta\|_1\leq s$, i.e., in the case $p=2$, the points inside the square with vertices $\{(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1)\}$.

Comment: I know that constraint is not an alipse, but it is square. I was writing that $RSS$ is constant  on elipses centered around least square estimator like at page 222 in "An Introduction to
Statistical Learning" by Tibshirani. That pdf can be found here http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ for free.

Comment: Ok. That's because the RSS, as a function of the betas, is a convex paraboloid.

Comment: I see that RSS is convex function of $\beta_{1},\beta_{2}$. Suppose I have a equation $f(\beta_1,\beta_2)=a \beta_{1}^2+2 b \beta_{1} \beta_{2}+c \beta_{2}^2=d$. I don't see that set of $(\beta_{1},\beta_{2})$ which solve this equation is ellipse. ($a,b,c,d$ are constant, of course we can make assumption that one of the constant is 1)

Comment: You should write down the loss function in the simplest case for $p=2$. Some suggestions: 
$$
RSS(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \beta_1 x_{1i} -\beta_2 x_{2i})^2
$$
after some computations:
$$
A\beta_1^2 + B\beta_1\beta_2 + C\beta_2^2 + D\beta_1 + E\beta_2 + F = 0
$$
then have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Ellipse_as_quadric).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for :) I though about change of variables but now I see that it is not so easy in my case. I am very thankful. So for $p > 2$ I will not try move the RSS into canonical p-dimensional ellipse :D I thought about another solution (in case $p=2$): find $\beta_{1}$ as function of $\beta_{2}$ and plot it.